# Using variables in another class to store integers (Swift in iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, function, if-statement, segue

I am building a simple tap war game where there are 2 sides of the screen spilt evenly down the middle. It is a 2 player game where the objective is to simply get to 20 taps first. Once a player does score 20 points, the code performs a segue to a restart screen. In this restart screen I want there to be a label where it displays the number of wins each player has. **How do I correctly reference the classes and integers in my if statement below to add a win to the winning player?** (I just want it to be something like Red: (redWins) Blue: (blueWins))

```
import UIKit

class endGameFinalScore {

    var ScoreInteger: String = ""
    var redWins: Int = 0
    var blueWins: Int = 0
}
```

In another view controller I test to see if either player has reached a score of 20. If the blue player scored 20, I want to add 1 to the integer that scores their number of wins.

```
func testEndGame() {

    if redScoreInt >= 20 {

        endGameFinalScore.redWins += 1
        redScoreInt = 0
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("endGameSegue", sender: nil)

    }

    if blueScoreInt >= 20 {

        endGameFinalScore.blueWins += 1
        blueScoreInt = 0
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("endGameSegue", sender: nil)

    }
```

Comment: This question is unclear, but it seems like what you want is a singleton in some namespace higher than your view controllers which the restart screen can refer to to get the wins information. This might also want to be available to your application delegate, so that scores can be saved across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override prepareForSegue method like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue!.identifier == "endGameSegue" {
            let vc = segue!.destinationViewController as restartScreenViewController
            vc.redWins = endGameFinalScore.redWins
            vc.blueWins = endGameFinalScore.blueWins
        }
    }
```